# "Alter user sys identified by" not working

Tags: sql, oracle

First of all, I use:

Windows 7 x64
Oracle Enterprise 11g R2 x32

I have some basic experience with SQL Server and MySQL (more with MySQL). Today I started working with Oracle, and I've been bumping a lot on the way.

The problem I'm having now is that, for some reason, I can't connect to any sys user (sysdba or sysoper). Probably I made a mistake writing the password when creating the database, but I'm not sure, so I'm trying to change it.

I've been trying, as some searches had led me to try, to use

```
sqlplus /nolog
connect / as sysdba
alter user sys identified by new_pass;
```

And it seems to work. I mean, it says "User altered". However, I still can't log in sqlplus with the new password. It's a little weird, since I can connect to "sysman" with my original password, but it doesn't have the privileges I need.

I'd appreciate any help I could get, and I thank you beforehand.

Comment: Try using an uppercase password - if it works, then it'll be because you're using an older client. Newer clients are needed to support mixed-case passwords in 11g.

Comment: By default passwords are case sensitive in Oracle 11. So `new_pass` is different than `NEW_PASS`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you log in with 'sqlplus / as sysdba', try changing the password for system by issuing

```
ALTER USER system IDENTIFIED BY abcdef;
```

Then, to make sure, without quitting sqlplus:

```
CONN system/abcdef
```

That should work.  After that, you can log on with system/abcdef when you start sqlplus.

Answer (score 0):

The ORA-01994 error happens when you forget to use the orapwd command, and it critical to note that the name of the file must be orapwsid, and you must supply the full path name when using the orapwd command. 'orapwsid' sid is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

A No Root password installation's the default. Now you were logged in as root@'%', but a bug exists. Compare how two SQL statements react:

```
 ALTER USER CURRENT_USER() IDENTIFIED BY 'mariadb';
```

Always outputs mysql_native_password |                                           |

```
alter user root@'%' identified by 'mariadb';
```

Job works and the root's identified by new password.

```
mysql_native_password | *54958E764C
```

Comment: This question is about Oracle Database, not MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

add quotes to the password

```
 sqlplus /nolog
 connect / as sysdba
 SQL>alter user sys identified by "KUQhkdhqedqwdhqdx";
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced same problem in my server and I resolved them by following solution.

steps of solution.

1)  change sys password from database connect with /as sysdba

2)  down application and database and restart both 1 database 2 application

3) start listener and database then application.

now both are working fine.